# Find $f'(5)$ , if $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ and $f'(0)=3$ and $f(5)=3$

Tags: calculus, functions

> It is a functional equation question: find $f'(5)$ , if $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ and $f'(0)=3$ and $f(5)=3$.

Comment: Now what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Plug in $y=5$, then take the derivative of both sides and after that plug in $x=0$ to get the final result.

Comment: By Cauchy's solution, shouldn't $f(x)=\dfrac{3x}{5}$ as $f(5)=3$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yeah I noticed that! It seems that the equation is contradicting itself. At the end I think that the purpose of the author was quite different, so he made all the conditions without worrying whether such a function is really possible. Anyway it seems like the author should have asked: "If such a function exist then what's the value of $f'(x)$ at $x=5$?".

Comment: But if done in the 1st approach (by using definition of derivative) then it doesn't seem like there is anything wrong with the answer.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yeah that's what I'm saying. Everything seems alright, but we take for granted that such a function in $\mathbb{R}$ exists, which seems not to be true.

Comment: So I think it's best not to refer to the Cauchy equation in this particular case. Or could I say that the question is not correct.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I agree. Maybe it would be better to delete the second paragraph, as it might confuse more than it can help.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*} f'(5) &=\lim_{h \to 0}{{f(5+h)-f(5)} \over h}\\ &=\lim_{h \to 0}{{f(5)+f(h)-f(5)} \over h}\\ &= \lim_{h \to 0}{{f(0)+f(h)-f(0)} \over h}\\ &= \lim_{h \to 0}{{f(0+h)-f(0)} \over h}\\ &=f'(0)\\ &=3 \end{align*}$$